# DoubleClick studio. Chromeless youtube player

Tags: double-click, rich-media

I need to use a youtube player component in a rich media banner I'm making. I can't find any chrome less version of the one from youtube?

I know there is one but how can i access it?

Comment: i would like to use it but not having any youtube branding..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a chromeless version available.
It's accessable through the YTPlayer Proxy Component, which can be downloaded here:
http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/docs/innovation/ytplayer/en/index.html

Then you have to set the playerType parameter like this:

```
var ytp:YTPlayer = new YTPlayer();
ytp.playerType = "chromeless"; 
//valid values "embedded" or "chromeless"
```

The full documentation (hard to find) for using the youtube player in doubleclick can be find here:
http://motifcdn2.doubleclick.net/EMEA/ad-in-a-box/YTP/DCRM_YouTube_Player_Component_EN.pdf